# Is it possible to export a single graph to multiple folders in one command in R.

Tags: r, graph, export

I want to export a png image (say "file.png") in to multiple folders.

```
    path_1 <- "C:/folder1/file.png"
    path_2 <- "C:/folder2/file.png"
```

Is it possible to export :

```
    png(c(path_1, path_2)) 
    dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply` or `plyr::l_ply` to achieve want to want (not a one-liner though)

```
lapply(c(path1, path2), function(path) {
  png(path)
  hist(rnorm(1000))
  dev.off()
})
```

For this type of task (i.e not output needed), I prefer to use `l_ply`

```
library(plyr)
l_ply(c(path1, path2), function(path) {
  png(path)
  hist(rnorm(1000))
  dev.off()
})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: cool :) Thanks. Though I have a conditional loop on two paths. So I am trying to print in both folders while some flag is TRUE or else in the respective ones on some given condition any idea how to start with it ?